# Moving files from Desktop to Usr/Java

Tags: java

I have a file I need to move from the Desktop folder to the `usr/java` folder.

- What I have tried:

  I tried using the Nautilus Files utility and got a "permission denied" error.
  I tried using `mv`, and got `Cannot Stat '/desktop/jre-8u241-linux-x64.tar.gz': No such file or directory`.

Comment: Classic newbie mistakes usually occur when you are trying to skip beginner steps. "Permission denied" means you didn't check the target directory's ownership. "No such file or directory" means you are being sloppy with your paths.

Comment: In layman's terms, permission denied (most of the time) means A) do you really want to do this? and B) put `sudo` before it if you really do.

Answer (score 1):

Your desktop is in `/home/your_user_name/Desktop`. Letters' register is important in Linux systems. `desktop` and `Desktop` are different folders. Also, run Nautilus as `root` from terminal, if you want it to work with root user's folders.

If you want to move files into root user's folders using terminal, use `sudo` command:

```
$ sudo mv /home/your_user_name/Desktop/jre-8u241-linux-x64.tar.gz /usr/java/
```